# Equalize row count between columns in Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### My Problem

I'm working on sentiment analysis using ML models.

I have a dataset of Amazon reviews from 1 to 5 stars.

```
print(df.groupby('overall').count())

overall    reviewText        
1.0          108725
2.0           82139
3.0          142257
4.0          347041
5.0         1009026
```

These results are biased, with 59% of them being 5-stars. I'm afraid if I train my model with this dataset, it will learn quickly to be biased towards rating a sentiment of 'Positive'.

I would like to equalize all of these rows so each 'overall' rating has an equal number of 'reviewText'

### My Current Solution

Here is my current solution

```
one_star_ratings = df.loc[df['overall'] == 1.0][0:80000]
two_star_ratings =  df.loc[df['overall'] == 2.0][0:80000]
three_star_ratings = df.loc[df['overall'] == 3.0][0:80000]
four_star_ratings =  df.loc[df['overall'] == 4.0][0:80000]
five_star_ratings = df.loc[df['overall'] == 5.0][0:80000]

df2 = pd.concat([one_star_ratings, two_star_ratings, three_star_ratings, four_star_ratings, 
five_star_ratings])
```

This works, but it is a naive solution.

### My question

I will encounter this issue frequently while working with datasets, and I am trying to find a better solution. Assume I had 100 categories, and not just 5. How can I better solve this problem without writing 100+ lines of code to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `groupby().head()` for this:

```
n_sample = 80000
df2 = df.groupby('overall').head(n_sample)
```

If you want to sample randomly:

```
df2 = df.sample(frac=1).groupby('overall').head(n_sample)
```

You can also use `sample` to randomly select the data:

```
df2 = df.groupby('overall')apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=n_sample))
```